# Was the Federation worried that Worf would be recognized?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the Star Trek: Deep Space Nine episode "Apocalypse Rising," Worf, Sisko, Odo, and O'Brien infiltrate Klingon territory in an attempt to expose Gowron as a Changeling.

[Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Apocalypse_Rising_(episode)) does not mention Worf undergoing surgical alteration, and my recollection is that Worf was, at the time, a traitor to the Empire. A traitor to the Klingon Empire in the Klingon military headquarters would certainly draw attention!

Was the Federation worried that Worf would be identified by the other Klingons and therefore spoil the mission?

Or, was this possibility considered, but offset by other factors, like Worf's excellent knowledge of Klingon customs, or the large amount of bloodwine at the Order of the Bat'leth ceremony?

Comment: the Federation was not worried.  Only Worf, Sisko, Odo, and O'Brien, plus a few of their associates and superiors, knew about the mission and thus could possibly worry about ways it could and might fail.  The Federation as a while was unaware of the mission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [script](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/499.txt), Worf is also disguised. You probably need to suspend your disbelief a little and assume that he's '*nearly unrecognisable*' to the average Klingon.

**[Apocalypse Rising](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/499.txt)**

> 30   INT. DUKAT'S BIRD OF PREY - BRIDGE
>
> Sisko ENTERS to find Worf (**whose appearance has been
> somewhat altered as in "SONS OF MOGH"),** and faux Klingons Odo and O'Brien waiting for him along with  Dukat. DAMAR, Dukat's former executive officer, is  seated at the helm.

**[Sons of Mogh](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/487.txt)**

> 33   INT. SURGERY (OPTICAL)
>
> There are TWO unconscious Klingon warriors lying on the
> bio-bed tables. Worf is wearing a Klingon uniform and
> sitting on the edge of a table while BASHIR applies a
> small hand-held medical DEVICE to his face. **The device
> is producing SCARS on Worf's face as BASHIR works.
> Worf is nearly unrecognizable with the scarring and
> with his hair down in the wild Klingon style**. Two N.D.
> Nurses are helping BASHIR.

Comment: Watching the episode again I don't see any scarring but Worf's facial hair is trimmed differently.